# Female dog pooping while stuck

Tags: dogs, behavior, breeding, defecation

I have a female dog that's in heat right now. Last night her and my male dog got stuck and she started popping.

Is that normal?

Comment: yes, i have seen it happen thrice. :) I am not sure if it is normal but i think its not a rare occurrence.